# visual studio command prompt string concatation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, command, command-prompt, svcutil.exe

Hi i want to execute the cd C:\iwatch\trunk\CPCE Client\EfileServiceClient command using variables pls help me out with the below variables.

I am saving this batch file in C:\iwatch\trunk folder so launchdir variable is have the folder name.

```
 call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
    Echo OFF
    set "var1=cd"
    set "var2=Client\EfileServiceClient"
    Echo Launchdir: "%~dp0"
    Echo Currentdir: "%CD%"
    set "var3=%cd% Launchdir%var2%
    Echo %var3%
    svcutil http://localhost:19012/EfileService/EfileService.svc
```

After executing the above batch file the proxy file is generating in C:\iwatch\trunk folder but i want to generate these files in C:\iwatch\trunk\CPCE Client\EfileServiceClient folder...

Answer (score 0):

Example script to help you out.

```
@echo off
echo.CD=%CD%
mkdir "New Folder"
set var2="New Folder"
cd %~dp0%var2%
echo.CD=%CD%
pause
```

In your case set var2 to `CPCE Client\EfileServiceClient` then `cd %~dp0%var2%`. Hope this help!